# I have some old smoked nuts- can I make anything with them?

Tags: nuts

They were smoked so they are not rancid. They are just rather flat in flavor. Are there any options for use? They are smoked almonds and brazil nuts.

Comment: Must.... resist....NSFW joke.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chopped coarsely, these could be well used as a textural addition to various kind of mock-minced-meat dishes, eg in a vegetarian bolognese, lasagna sauce, mapo dofu sauce...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you'd like to do this because my answer is kinda simple but, you can make candied nuts with the almonds. As for the Brazil nuts, I would add them to salads. For example, add it in to dressing. This is because it has a tangy taste to it. Or you could use it in pastas. Just shred it like cheese and add it over the pasta. Don't know if this helped but, that's my advice.